# Eigen::MatrixXf to a std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f>

Tags: c++, dictionary, casting, std, eigen

My ultimate goal is to convert very efficiently a Point Cloud `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` to `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f>`.
The function `getMatrixXfMap()` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274675/eigen-with-pointcloud-pcl)) allows me to convert the Point Cloud to a `Eigen::MatrixXf`.

How could I convert now the `Eigen::MatrixXf`into a `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f>`? (or if you know a direct method to go from the `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` to `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f>` that also works for me)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813340/stdvectoreigenvector3d-to-eigenmatrixxd-eigen) answer is exactly the other way around

UPDATE: This is what I have so far (it works, but it's slower than iterating through all the points). I'm casting to double in this case, but any solution without casting to double also works for me:

```
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pclptr_map_;
  // Do stuff 
  Eigen::MatrixXd mat = (pclptr_map_->getMatrixXfMap()).cast<double>();
  int cols = pclptr_map_->points.size();
  std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> v(pclptr_map_->points.size());
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, Eigen::Dynamic>::Map(v.data()->data(), 3, cols) = mat;
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682743/how-to-map-a-eigenmatrix-to-stdvectoreigenvector

Comment: Do you actually also want to covert from float to double?

Comment: No, I've just updated the question, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> to Eigen::MatrixXd Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813340/stdvectoreigenvector3d-to-eigenmatrixxd-eigen)